# Magento 2 not fully secured error and admin not working

Tags: magento

I recently installed a godaddy ssl certificate on my magento site. My home page loads fine with no mixed content. However, all the links in the navigation menu are being generated as http:// and the cart page has mixed content warnings. My config is:

```
Auto redirect to base url: no 
use web server rewrites: no 
use secure urls in frontend: yes 
use secure urls in admin: yes 
offloader header: SSL_OFFLOADED.
```

Please tell me that how can I call my all http catalog product to https.

How do I get rid of all the mixed content? Which files do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento Admin, navigate to

Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System.

Expand the Full Page Cache section, then Fastly Configuration, then Advanced Configuration.

Click the Force TLS button, and make sure the current state of Force TLS is displayed as enabled.

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions